# Is there a way to slow down the loading of assets in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser

does anyone now how I could artificially slow the speed of assets (images, js, etc) as if my local site was loading over the internet? Someway of saying "load the site as if it was loading over a 756kbps" or something like that. This could possibly be a browser plugin as well.

Comment: This might help: http://superuser.com/questions/330501/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using "speedlimit": http://mschrag.github.com/ from the link that reuben posted.